# How to impose LDAP IP restrictions?

Tags: java, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I am new to Lightweight DA services and for my task I need to be able to add new entries to an LDAP server.However, only certain(configurable) IPs (application instances) should be allowed to perform the add operation.

What is the best way to approach this?

I am using Java 8 and UnboundId sdk.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The language and API you are using are irrelevant. It's a configuration step at the server. Off topic.

Comment: Well as I said I am new to LDAP, so I didn't know if it was possible to configure the server to reject certain IPs (even though authentication may be successful)